# Bokeh: display image on plot axis legend ticks

Tags: python-3.x, image, bar-chart, bokeh, axis-labels

Is there a way to get Bokeh to display an image on axis ticks instead of a string or a numerical value?

For example

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

images = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png"]
p = figure(x_range=images, plot_height=250, title="Stuff",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")
p.vbar(x=images, top=[5, 3, 4], width=0.9)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
show(p)
```

results in

[image: barplot]

How can I get images to show instead of the "img.png" text?

```
from IPython.display import Image
images1 = [Image(x) for x in images]
```

doesn't work.